# Memory usage: Commit, Working Set, Shareable, Private different with VS2015 Diagnostic Tools

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, virtual-memory, resource-monitor

The windows Resource Monitor shows the memory usage of my app (debug running in visual studio) in the following figure:

[image]

However, the Diagnostic Tools shows the memory graph like:

[image]

The `Commit size` is

> The Amount of virtual memory reserved by the operating system for the process in KB.

Does this mean all memory allocated in my app?

And the **`Private` size in Resource Monitor is much less than it in the Diagnostic Tools**, is the `Private` in the Resource Monitor doesn't count the pages that are swapped out into disk? So the `Private + Shareable = Working Set`.

Even the **Process Memory** in the graph is different from the **Heap Size** in the Diagnostic Tools, apart from Heap Size is there any Stack Size that will be 100M large?
[image]

Comment: It's important to remember that "virtual memory" is not synonymous with "swap file".   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: @xaxxon Yes, but isn't the size of swap file and physical usage add up to the size of virtual memory used by a executable

Comment: My incomplete understanding is that the "commit" is a reserved chunk that is bigger than what is actually used and is expanded as your app approaches the currently reserved amount.

Comment: I can't tell what the question is here.

Comment: I suggest watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjTl53I_qzY (and the 2nd part) as potential refresher and source of insight on why tools may report different numbers for what they would name similarly, etc.